# Why is the mode a measure of central tendency?

Tags: statistics, central-tendency

Is mode a measure of central tendency just because it's the most frequent? Is it enough to say that it's in the center? I think it's lame, and there might be some other reason why we call it a measure of central tendency. But, I don't know the reason.

Comment: Measures of central tendency allow you to better understand the distribution by comparing them. For example if I know the mode is much lower than the average it tells me something about how the distribution is weighted. Most distributions don't have a well-defined center so I wouldn't call any measure of central tendency the middle or center.

Comment: I wouldn't say "just" because it is the most frequent. It is a measure of central tendency because it is the most frequent.

Comment: I don't think I get my answer. But, thanks for the time.

Comment: In answer, it is called a measure of central tendency because it is a measure of central tendency. There is no other reason.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same doubt, what I inferred. To answer the question briefly, mode is the central tendency of probability, that is out of all the sampled observations the data (at mode) has the highest probability to occur again.

Central Tendency (under a criterion) could mean the propensity of the next data point (w.r.t the chosen criterion). It could also mean "effective value to contain / describe the entire data".

Mean - *scale* (central tendency in **magnitude**).
Median - *position* (central tendency in **order of occurrence**) .
Mode - *frequency* (central tendency in **probability of occurrence**).

Think Mean
All the "values of" observations contribute to a "magnitude" $[M = \sum f_i]$ . Then, mean would be this magnitude "in scale of" each individual observation $[mean = M / n]$.  That is, the data in scope of magnitude is  centrally placed at mean (centre of least magnitude to highest magnitude presented by each observation) *OR* the next data point is likely to occur at this scale.

> Think average class score. It means less for each student but can explain the performance of the teacher.

Think Median
Let's say the data is ordered (even if it is not; order could be induced but it is often the sequence of occurrence (time)). Then, each observation is indexed, that is, each data point is "positioned" in corresponding order. Thus, data in scope of order is centrally placed at median (centre of first in order to last in order of each observation). The next data point will never fall on the median but it does describe the dataset.

> Think of the score of a football game at the start, end and half-time.

Think Mode
Let's say each individual observation in data is unique and susceptible to recurrence (through invocation). Mode is not the central tendency of frequency, but tendency of the probability of next data point "to be" the data point at mode. The context of centre is different here.

> Imagine blinking christmas-lights. Freeze time and the light at mode would (probably) be lit.

Answer (score 0):

Imagine, you made a questionaire “What is your favourite colour?” and got the following answers:

```
red, green, red, blue, black, black, red, yellow, white, pink
```

What is a central tendency here? Of course, you might transform the colours to RGB and calculate the mean. Or you can arrange the colours from dark to light and find the median. Or you can say “red” is the colour that people choose the most.

If you want to describe a distribution in general the first thing you may ask “where the values approximately are?” and then “how concentrated they are?”. Different ways to answer the first question are called the central tendency, answers to the second question are called variability.

Many natural distributions are unimodal and if they have a mean/median, it's not far from the mode. Thus, the mode is a good measure of central tendency. But you can think of it as lame, of course, no one can stop you from that.